# Display Strings with SharedPreferences does not work

Tags: android, sharedpreferences, textview, android-resources, android-sharedpreferences

I've created a method to get a String from `strings.xml` with `SharedPreferences` and display it in a `TextView`. There is no error report but the `TextView` shows nothing. Is there a problem with `SharedPreferences`? The Strings and `TextView` are correct.

```
public void setQuestion() {
    TextView Question = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.question);
    if (question == 0) {
        SharedPreferences sharedPreferences =
                getSharedPreferences("strings", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        String myquestion = sharedPreferences.getString("AppQuestion1", "");
        Question.setText(myquestion);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `strings.xml` and `SharedPreferences` are different things.

If your `AppQuestion1` is defined in the `strings.xml` like below:

```
<string name="AppQuestion1">Question1: ...</string>
```

You can get the String by calling `getString` method on your `Resources` object.

```
String myquestion = getResources().getString(R.string.AppQuestion1);
```

And there is no need to use `SharedPreferences`.

Comment: But if I want to edit a String in strings.xml I have to use SharedPreferences?

Comment: Yes. Resources including strings.xml stores predefined data. If you want to store some kind of dynamically changing data, you have to use storage options including SharedPrefereces. See: [Google's API Guide](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html). And when you stack another problem, post a new question on stackoverflow.com again.

Comment: ok thanks! Yeah I thought this question is to short to create a new question :)